# Closing duplicate tabs in macOS Safari

Tags: macos, safari

There's a tonne of questions about how to duplicate Safari tabs but I can't find a single one that helps with the opposite - closing duplicates.

I have nearly 300 tabs open and going through them by hand is going to take forever. I know I can sort them to make it a bit easier but it's still going to be very time consuming and doesn't really work if the tab title changes because of a notification for example. Is there any quicker way of getting rid of duplicates?